# is it possible to embed a document from Google drive with php api

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

is it possible to embed Google Drive File with PHP API without Direct access. 
I am trying different methods such as
The file has access the "anyone" with link

- file_get_contents
- CURL
- readfile

> ```
> header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
> header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
> header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.basename($file));
> header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
> header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
> header('Expires: 0');
> header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
> header('Pragma: public');
> header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
> ob_clean();
> flush();
> ```